# RewriteRule giving 500 error when adding dynamic id at url end

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am getting a 500 Internal Server Error from my linked CSS files etc when I use this htaccess code.. Anyone know what might be the problem? I am not too fluent in htaccess yet.

Here is the code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(system|img|res) - [L]

RewriteRule ^picture/([^/]*)/?$ picture.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]

## The below code is something I found on the internet to remove the .php tag
# remove .php; use THE_REQUEST to prevent infinite loops
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.mywebsite\.com
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ (.*)\.php\ HTTP
RewriteRule (.*)\.php$ $1 [R=301]

# remove index
RewriteRule (.*)index$ $1 [R=301]

# remove slash if not directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /$
RewriteRule (.*)/ $1 [R=301]

# add .php to access file, but don't redirect
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule (.*) $1\.php [L]
```

The URL is supposed to be: www.mysite.com/pictures/1 (id)

The id is always a number.

It does show me the page and I can echo the id, so that part is working, however it gives me a 500 error on linked files as mentioned above.

Comment: What does the - on line 3 mean?

Comment: "RewriteRule ^(system|img|res) - [L]" is supposed to ignore the folders: system,img and res, which it does fine as of now at least. :-)

Comment: @Darkwater It means to "passthrough without rewriting the URI". I don't see anything wrong with these rules,

Comment: What's the link to the CSS file that's causing the 500 error?

Comment: I do not get 500 error on the page I am trying to rewrite the URL for, but the CSS files gets a 500 error for some reason, which means I only get a page with raw HTML output without any styles set etc.

The CSS link is like this: 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="./css/text.css" />

Comment: **"The CSS link is like this: `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="./css/text.css" />`"** And where is the actual CSS file? Is it in `/picture/css/text.css`?

Comment: I just figured it out, I had to add ../ in front of the link.. :-)
Not sure why it acts like that tho.. The CSS folder is in the same folder as the actual php file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Not sure why it acts like that tho.. The CSS folder is in the same folder as the actual php file.

You've linked to it using a relative URI:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="./css/text.css" />
```

e.g. the `./css/text.css`, and while the css file may be in the same directory as `picture.php` file (which I assume is what is generating the content) but the browser is what actually makes the request for the CSS, not the picture.php script. The browser requests this URL `http://www.mysite.com/picture/1`, and the server internally rewrite the `/picture/1` to `/picture.php?id=1`, the browser has no clue that's happened. So it sees the base URI as `/picture/`. If the browser went directly to the php file: `http://www.mysite.com/picture.php?id=1`, the base URI would be `/` and the css would resolve just fine to `/./css/text.css`. But the `/picture/1` request has a different base URI so the browser (with no clue that the base is different) blindly attempts to retrieve the css as `/picture/./css/text.css`, which fails because you have rules that mishandle that URI. Normally you'd just get a 404, but the rules you have after the picture rewrite mishandles the URI and returns a 500 server error.

You can either add in your header:

```
<base href="/">
```

in the content generated by `picture.php`, or make the URI's absolute:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="/css/text.css" />
```

Comment: Thanks for that explaining! Really informative and good to know for future reference!